# how to count multiple columns as score

Tags: postgresql, query

I want to prepare query which will count score from such data

score should be sum of:

```
 1. rating (1 if rated but not watched, 5 if rated and watched)
 2. favourite (1 if favourited but not watched, 5 if favourited and watched)
```

result table should have data for every user where counted score is > 0 and for every talk he scored like

```
user | talk | score |
A    | abc  | 1     |
B    | abc  | 5     |
B    | xyz  | 10    |
...
```

I have created such query for this but I have duplicated rows where same user and talk pair is seen multiple times (and should be only once)

```
SELECT 
    users.id as userID,
    talks.id as talkID,
    sum(
        CASE WHEN user_talks_favourited.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NOT NULL THEN 5 
             WHEN user_talks_favourited.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NULL THEN 1
        END + 
        CASE WHEN talk_ratings.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NOT NULL THEN 5 
        WHEN talk_ratings.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NULL THEN 1 END
        + 0
    ) as score 
FROM talks 
LEFT JOIN talk_ratings ON talk_ratings.talk_id = talks.id 
LEFT JOIN user_talks_favourited ON user_talks_favourited.talk_id = talks.id 
LEFT JOIN user_talk_watch_progress ON user_talk_watch_progress.talk_id = talks.id 
LEFT JOIN users ON talk_ratings.user_id = users.id
    or user_talk_watch_progress.user_id = users.id
    or user_talks_favourited.user_id = users.id 

GROUP BY talks.id, users.id, user_talks_favourited.user_id, user_talk_watch_progress.user_id 
order by users.id
```

another issue here is that not rated talks should also not be listed (but they are)

**EDIT:**

I have updated query to list only "connected" talks to users but score is [null] for every row now

```
SELECT 
    users.id as userID,
    talks.id as talkID,
    sum(
        CASE WHEN user_talks_favourited.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NOT NULL THEN 5 
             WHEN user_talks_favourited.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NULL THEN 1
        END + 
        CASE WHEN talk_ratings.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NOT NULL THEN 5 
        WHEN talk_ratings.user_id = users.id AND user_talk_watch_progress.watched_date IS NULL THEN 1 END
        + 0
    ) as score 
FROM users 

LEFT JOIN talk_ratings ON talk_ratings.user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN user_talks_favourited ON user_talks_favourited.user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN user_talk_watch_progress ON user_talk_watch_progress.user_id = users.id 
JOIN talks ON talk_ratings.talk_id = talks.id
    or user_talk_watch_progress.talk_id = talks.id
    or user_talks_favourited.talk_id = talks.id 

GROUP BY talks.id, users.id, user_talks_favourited.user_id, user_talk_watch_progress.user_id 
order by talks.id, users.id
```

EDIT: updated with table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_talk_watch_progress
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    talk_id uuid NOT NULL,
    started_watching_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    half_watched_date timestamp with time zone,
    watched_date timestamp with time zone,
    current_progress integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_talk_watch_progress_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_talk_watch_progress_talk_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (talk_id)
        REFERENCES public.talks (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT user_talk_watch_progress_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE public.user_talks_favourited
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    talk_id uuid NOT NULL,
    favourited_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_talks_favourited_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_talks_favourited_talk_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (talk_id)
        REFERENCES public.talks (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT user_talks_favourited_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE public.talk_ratings
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    talk_id uuid NOT NULL,
    rating boolean NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT talk_ratings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT talk_ratings_talk_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (talk_id)
        REFERENCES public.talks (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT talk_ratings_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE public.talks
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    title text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT talks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
)

CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    role userrole NOT NULL,
    last_active timestamp with time zone,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Remove `user_talks_favourited.user_id, user_talk_watch_progress.user_id` from `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I doubt that somebody will answer. Too complex query without DDLs and data samples. *I have duplicated rows where same user and talk pair is seen multiple times (and should be only once)* GROUP BY allows duplicates by a part of grouping expression - it guarantees the unqueness by the whole expression only.

Comment: I have added DDLs

Comment: @Lennart I got error when I remove them

Comment: @PawełMadej, what error did you get? After fixing some minor issues with your ddl, the modified query works for me:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=89c7e35d59a3196739ab607798f29350

Comment: @lennart hmm ... I used yours and it works but score is still calculated as null

Comment: Add some sample data that Illustrated the problem and post back the fiddle url. My guess would be that nothing matches case which results in null

Comment: @Lennart here is fiddle with example data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=281d949323088157f8ec4ed8c3cd4fa4

result should show for talkID `b3871...` score 5 for talkID `b1bb7...` score 1 and third one should not be listed.

Comment: Is this as expected? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=679385796c1b3ef22841bbce1b5241b3

Comment: Unfortunately no should be as above 1 and 5

Comment: I have figured it out: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1bc305cdd2d592be9c81db89c96de56e